# Tailwind Css doesn't work on Codesandbox with default React template?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, codesandbox

so I've tried to tryout Tailwind on codesandbox, but it seems like it doesn't work for some reason when adding the lib as dependency. If I add it from CDN it works fine.

I've followed docs to configure it properly with CRA (at least in my opinion)...

Also, the exact I've created CRA locally, and configured it exactly the same way and locally it looks fine. Does anyone know the reason? Or maybe theres something wrong with my configuration? I've seem that other people manage to run Tailwind (on other versions thou). Am I doing something wrong?

Here's link to sandbox (I've added basic Tailwind class in App.js): https://codesandbox.io/s/young-fast-oqu96k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Seems like tailwind apps require a bit more configuration than what the default react environment of code sandbox provides. You could try forking the template and starting from there: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-playground-kkkzc?file=/README.md

Comment: Tailwind scans your entire app to find classes and it does it before the app is built so it requires additional configuration

Comment: If you are still looking for a solution, try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75680444/5814078