# Tailwindcss classes not applying in Codesandbox

Tags: tailwind-css, codesandbox, tailwind-3

I'm trying to use tailwindcss in my codesandbox, but it's not applying. I added this through the "Add Dependnecy" option and also it's showing in package.json as well. But can't see in dependencies section of codesandbox. Also, added its layers in css file which is being imported in "index.js".
Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "circular-progressbar-demo-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "3.2.22",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Here is the link to codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/circular-progressbar-demo-2-molcnd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your project has no tailwind.config.js and has no integration to react, you probably need different setup to make it run in codesandbox. here is an example with html. https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-playground-kkkzc?file=/package.json notice that they run the tailwind as a postcss cli comand. it is similar in codesandbox react as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding the tailwind CDN in `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> // add this
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Hello world!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that was simple 